# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: java

As I have installed MS office 2007 on Windows 7 64 bit and I also installed jdk 32 and 64 bit but when I try to connect to MS Access ans I already created system DSN the above exception throws by the code

Comment: you installed both 32 and 64 ; did you remove 32 before install 64 or they both exists?

Answer (score 0):

There's no ODBC bridge driver DLL in the Java 64 bit code base, so perhaps that's the problem.  You'll either have to buy a JDBC driver that can connect to Access or switch databases.  Derby comes bundled with JDK 6 and higher.  Perhaps that will serve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Java code is not bit specific and as "duffymo" says there is no ODBC bridge in Java. The ODBC bridge you are using is calling the MS ODBC driver manager with the same bit size as the ODBC bridge. The error is comming back because the ODBC driver the driver manager is trying to open is of a different size.

To resolve this you simply need to make sure the the ODBC Bridge is of the same bit size as the MS Access ODBC driver is on your machine.